# how to use a column from select query result in "if condition" of Stored Procedure in SQL

Tags: sql

how to use a column from select query result in "if condition" of Stored Procedure in SQL.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Most dbms products have their own versions of stored procedures.) Also show us your current code attempt.

Answer (score -1):

for stored procedure :
    use cursor. get column values in variable and then use if condition.

example from mysql:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE build_email_list (INOUT email_list varchar(4000))
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_email varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

 -- declare cursor for employee email
 DEClARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT email FROM employees;

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 OPEN email_cursor;

 get_email: LOOP

 FETCH email_cursor INTO v_email;

 IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_email;
 END IF;

 -- build email list
 SET email_list = CONCAT(v_email,";",email_list);

 END LOOP get_email;

 CLOSE email_cursor;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

for sql query :
    use subquery.